# Conexões de rede entre processos dentro de uma máquina

Tags: windows, cmd, redes, ip, tcp

ao dar o comando netstat -na no cmd do windows aparecem as conexões de rede que estão em andamento na máquina.

Na minha apareceram diversas conexões tendo como IP de origem e destino o "127.0.0.1" que é o endereço "interno", ou seja, comunicação da própria máquina com ela mesma.

Alguém sabe porque o Windows faz isso? Ao invés de usar simplesmente (e somente) a comunicação entre processos? (Pipes, fifos, mensagens, sinais...)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para sua pergunta não ficar vaga, seria interessante adicionar print desse comando que você diz apresentar conexoes internas.

Comment: Coloquei a imagem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine que você precise testar sua aplicação cliente-servidor ou peer-to-peer consigo mesmo, sua máquina não está conectada na Internet, nem tem um IP real, e o protocolo de rede é o TCP/IP. Que endereço você usaria para se conectar consigo mesmo?

Bem, a IETF escreveu há muito a RFC 5735, que, entre outras coisas, define endereços IP especiais, como este, o `127.0.0.1`, chamado **loopback**. É um endereço fixo que aponta sempre para a própria máquina. Utilizar o domínio `localhost` resulta no mesmo, porque no arquivo `hosts` do sistema operacional `localhost`está mapeado para `127.0.0.1`.

A aplicação nunca se encarrega da rede. Para ela não faz diferença se você está rodando o cliente e o servidor na mesma máquina ou em máquinas diferentes. Ela apenas vai obter a configuração de IP e porta que lhe for passada e pedir ao sistema operacional enviar a comunicação. Mas, quando se envia algo para `127.0.0.1`, o sistema operacional nem se dá ao trabalho de enviar para além da placa de rede. O driver de rede TCP/IP passa direto para a porta da aplicação.

Existem outras utilidades menores deste endereço. Como por exemplo testar se o protocolo de comunição de rede instalado é o TCP/IP versão IPv4, com o comando `$ ping 127.0.0.1`. O sistema operacional precisa entender este endereço.

Comment: Ok, eu também uso o loop back para testar exercícios de programação que usam sockets, mas isso não explica porque o meu windows tem tantas conexões desse tipo abertas sabe.

Comment: Experimente rodar o netstat assim: `netstat --program`. Isto irá mostrar qual programa deixou a porta aberta. Às vezes é o próprio Firefox...

Comment: @C.Bohok netstat -b , requer nível elevado

Comment: Então vai ser preciso pedir ajuda para o Admin da rede para executar o comando como `su`. Eu desconheço outra forma de saber qual programa está abrindo as portas, além da forma mencionada `netstat --program`. Se alguém souber, favor comentar aqui, eu também gostaria de saber.

Answer (score 0):

> Alguém sabe porque o Windows faz isso? Ao invés de usar simplesmente (e somente) a comunicação entre processos? (Pipes, fifos, mensagens, sinais...)

Não é bem o windows que faz isso, há sim alguns serviços nele que fazem isso, mas a maioria são de outros programas que deve ter instalado no seu computador.

Imagine um servidor de banco de dados, toda a comunicação é feita por TCP/IP, porque ele deve funcionar via rede. E para a comunicação local, ele continua a utilizar o TCP/IP, porém com o endereço loopback.

Imagine a complicação para desenvolver uma comunicação de rede e uma local (entre processos, mensagens, pipes, etc) apenas para não gerar essas conexões em loopback. Totalmente desnecessário.

Utilize `netstat -a -b` para ver quais são os executáveis que estão escutando ou comunicando com essas portas, ou então um software `tcpview.exe` da Sysinternals que mostra detalhada todas as comunicações do SO.

Download tcpview: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: Entendi. Mas ao criar uma conexão local ao invés da simples comunicação entre processos, não acaba sendo mais custoso pra máquina?